# Nest Subcategories in R on X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that I am playing with and learning about in R. I am attempting to accomplish a visualization where there are multiple models of a particular item with several sub categories of data  for each item that I need to display. Each model has the same subcategories of data, I.E. Model A has Spec1, Spec2, Spec3, Spec4, and Spec5. I want to list out ModelA, ModelB, ModelC, and show their respective data values above each model. I have pivoted the table of data from one row listing the model and each subcategory, to each row displaying a different sub cateory of data, where you may see the model several times. I am not sure if that is how I need to wrangle the data to begin with, but I found a tutorial showing a similar visualization that worked for them, but it didnt work for me. I am somewhat stuck, and I am looking for advice on how to accomplish this quickly and effectively, as I am new to R. I am not sure I am asking the right questions or attempting to wrangle correctly in the first place. Thanks for any advice

I tried the following code

```
barchart <- ggplot()
barchart <- barchart +
  geom_col(
    ata = dataset,
    aes(x = dataCategories, y = dataNumbers, ),
    position = "dodge"
  )
barchart
```

I also tried this

```
barchart <- ggplot()
barchart <- barchart +
  geom_col(
    main.cat = c("productName"),
    second.cat = c("subcat1", "subcat2", "subcat3", "supcat4", "subcat5"),
    value = c("dataNumbers")
  )
```

Comment: Weclome to SO! From the description of what you are trying to achieve something like `ggplot(dataset) + geom_col(aes(x = CATEGORIES, y = NUMBERS, fill = SUBCATEGORIES), position = "dodge")` might be give you your desired result. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. As is we can't tell whether your data is in the right shape or needs some additional wrangling.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Note that the test data is in the long format.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
})

df1 %>%
  mutate(
    productName = factor(productName, levels = productName %>% unique()),
    subcat = sub("[[:alpha:]]+", "", subcat)
  ) %>%
  group_by(productName) %>%
  mutate(Group = interaction(subcat, productName, sep = "&")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Group, dataNumbers, group = subcat)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), fill = "steelblue") +
  labs(x = "Model", y = "Data Numbers") +
  guides(x = ggh4x::guide_axis_nested(delim = "&")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Test data

```r
set.seed(2023)
Model <- sprintf("Model%s", LETTERS[1:3])
subcat <- sprintf("Spec%d", 1:5)
df1 <- expand.grid(subcat, Model)[2:1]
names(df1) <- c("productName", "subcat")
df1$dataNumbers <- sample(10:20, nrow(df1), TRUE)
df1
#>    productName subcat dataNumbers
#> 1       ModelA  Spec1          14
#> 2       ModelA  Spec2          18
#> 3       ModelA  Spec3          17
#> 4       ModelA  Spec4          12
#> 5       ModelA  Spec5          19
#> 6       ModelB  Spec1          11
#> 7       ModelB  Spec2          10
#> 8       ModelB  Spec3          10
#> 9       ModelB  Spec4          10
#> 10      ModelB  Spec5          10
#> 11      ModelC  Spec1          14
#> 12      ModelC  Spec2          17
#> 13      ModelC  Spec3          11
#> 14      ModelC  Spec4          12
#> 15      ModelC  Spec5          13
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>